Crystal Report not getting database name on some machines
I am using Crystal Reports from a C# application written in Visual Studio 2019. The report works inside the VS2019 application, in my published application installed on my development PC and on one other PC, but on other PCs on the network, the application shows a connection dialog where the database name is blank and the logon fails.
I have a second VS2019 / C# application that uses Crystal Reports and all the reports in that application work on all PCs. The two applications access different servers.
Built the application with platform target of "any CPU" and x64 (prefer 32 is off).
